# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' i get this when i want to multiplied my name by my name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, math

When I want to print "Arsham" multiplied to "Arsham", I get this Error in my terminal can someone tell me why?

I Try'd to print my name multiplied by my name, and I expecting to my program show me `"Arsham" \* "Arsham"`

Comment: How do you print it? `print("\"Arsham\" \\* \"Arshham\"")`. https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted.

Comment: Hi. You say *"I get this Error in my terminal"* but you didn't actually show us the error message. It would help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strings can't multiplied to strings. In Python, Strings can multiplied only to integers.

```py
print("Arsham"*2)  # output is ArshamArsham
```

If your output should be `"Arsham" \* "Arsham"` than this code will help you

```py
print("Arsham", "\\*", "Arsham")
```

Comment: The output of this code does not match OP's expectations

Answer (score 1):

You will find an f-string useful for this:

```
name = "Arsham"

print(f'"{name}" \\* "{name}"')
```

**Output:**

```
"Arsham" \* "Arsham"
```

Or... using join:

```
name = '"Arsham"'

print(' \\* '.join([name]*2))
```